# Titanium - createAlertDialog on iOS with secure_text_input with number pad keyboard?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, titanium, appcelerator

How to enable numberpad in a Alert Dialog?

This code will not open load the number pad

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    style : Titanium.UI.iPhone.AlertDialogStyle.SECURE_TEXT_INPUT,
    message : 'Please Login',
    maxLength : 4,
    keyboardType : Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD,
    buttonNames : ['Logout', 'Login'],
    title : 'Login'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `keyboardType` property is not supported by an alert dialog in Titanium. That is for a TextField only.

So you cant do this with Titanium, another approach would be to make a custom alert out of a Ti.UI.View with an embedded TextField.

[DOC Quick Reference.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AlertDialog)